# Binance Future Trading Is Haram or Halal

Tags: halal-haram

As Binance saying `On Binance Futures, the interest rate is fixed at 0.03% daily (0.01% per funding interval), with the exception of contracts such as BNBUSDT, LINKUSDT, and LTCUSDT, where interest rates are 0%. Meanwhile, the premium varies according to the price difference between the perpetual contract and mark price.`

My question is i am not paying any interest because i am not holding more then hours , also i am not borrowing money from them just using my own money  , just there is liquidation problem well if i have some funds to increase liquidation So it will be haram or i can do it?

Comment: I'd recommend you rephrase your question as what you are doing is speculative day trading in futures & options. Irrespective of the exchange you are trading on, there is a significant difference between "Investment" and "Day Trading". One is Halal under the right criteria while the other is preferable to be avoided.